# GTX 660 fan fault, not running under normal operation

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

Had several crash to black screens today, popped open my case while up and running to find the fan not spinning at all.

- Fan spins momentarily on boot (~1 second)
- Fan then stops
- Play game, temp goes > 100degC
- Card panics, screens go black, system locks up and fan spins at 100%

I'm running the latest driver 358.91 - WHQL. Been doing so for around a week, this only started happening today.

As a temporary fix I'm thinking of hooking the fan directly to the PC power supply.

Screenshots from NVIDIA tools under linux, issue present in both Ubuntu and Windows 8.1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBkC3.jpg

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could be time for an upgrade too :P

Comment: What manufacturer's card is it? Also @Insane nah, GTX660 ftw.

Comment: @Leathe Oh I know, I got one myself. But that's not to say it didn't die at one point and I didn't get it RMA'd at one point from EVGA (at one point) :P

Comment: What would fan control software do?  If the fan isn't running outside of an operating system then the fan is likely dead and should be replaced.  "As a temporary fix I'm thinking of hooking the fan directly to the PC power supply." - This won't cool the GPU enough.

Comment: @benjaminS I've tried to manually set the speed using NV Inspector to no avail

Comment: @Ramhound temporary fix would leave fan in situ so would very much cool the card enough

Comment: @will - Your more then welcome to try it.  I just know it won't work ,if you are reading 100+ degC, a fan not in contact with the heatsink won't allow it to disppsiate the heat fast enough.

Comment: @Ramhound you misunderstand me, I'll be powering the (currently non-funtcional) GPU fan. Bodging the card back into operation, albeit noisily.